# My Queen ant has laid eggs but has not dropped her wings, is this ok?

Tags: species-identification, ant

My Queen ant has laid eggs but has not dropped her wings! I caught this Queen in England, I've had her for three days and she's laid eggs already but I was expecting her to to drop her wings first as she needs the wing muscles to feed her brood. I don't yet know the species of the queen but I'm suspecting it's a camponotus queen but I'm not sure, the queen is 1cm long and 4mm wide, the gastor is bigger than the thorax and she is black. (I haven't got a recent photo of the queen because I am currently away on holiday and will be for the next month. (My mum is still at home though so that's how I know there are eggs and the queen still has her wings)).Is there a species of ant that never drop there wings or don't drop them for a long time? 
[image]

Comment: You might have better luck asking some of your questions on a forum specifically for ant-keeping. Not so much that your questions are off-topic here, but we have a relatively small community and it might be quite some time before someone with the relevant expertise comes across these questions.